# Linking two containers in a single task definition in AWS fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, streamlit, aws-fargate, duckdb

Hi I am trying to deploy two containers one for DUCKDB which gets data from my s3 bucket and the other is a streamlit container which displays the frontend with some text box and dashboarding on the data collected from S3( A text box to run some random queries and display the results) Now I am finding it difficult to figure out how would both the containers communicate with each other as the duckdb container is listening to port 5000 and the streamlit one is listening to port 8501

Do I need to make changes to my python files used for duckb and streamlit. I mean I can deploy both of them on local host but not sure what would be the duckdb url in my code in the case of deploying it on cloud. Moreover while specifying the port mapping I need to write both 5000 and 8501 in the case of streamlit as it is in my dockerfile for streamlit ( EXPOSE 8501 5000)

Answer (score 0):

> not sure what would be the duckdb url in my code in the case of deploying it on cloud

Per [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/fargate-task-networking.html), multiple containers in the same task running on Fargate can connect to each other using `localhost` and the respective port.

So your Python app would connect to DuckDB at `localhost:5000`